# PHP - Silex: Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, silex, directadmin

I've made a PHP application with Silex. I'm using a WAMP solution on my laptop to develop, in combination with Composer.

Now, when I upload the application (maps 'app', 'src' and 'web') and upload the database, change the config.php to the correct database credentials I issue the composer command (composer.phar -o install) to install the vendor dependencies.

Until this point everything works, Composer makes the 'vendor' map and installs the dependencies without errors. But when I visit the website it shows me the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'WanaKo\Provider\Controller\HomeController' not found in /home/wanako/domains/wanako.net/app/app.php on line 37
```

What can I do to fix that error? I must add that the server is running DirectAdmin with PHP 5.5.16 and that I've made a symlink from 'public_html/' to 'web/'

The directory structure is:

```
/home/wanako/domains/wanako.net/
├── app
├── logs
├── public_ftp
│   └── incoming
├── public_html -> web/
├── src
│   ├── wanako
│   │   ├── provider
│   │   │   └── controller
│   │   └── repository
│   └── views
│       ├── errors
│       └── home
├── vendor
│   ├── composer
│   ├── doctrine
│   │   ├── common
│   │   └── dbal
│   ├── igorw
│   │   └── config-service-provider
│   ├── imagine
│   │   └── imagine
│   ├── ircmaxell
│   │   └── password-compat
│   ├── knplabs
│   │   └── repository-service-provider
│   ├── monolog
│   │   └── monolog
│   ├── neutron
│   │   └── silex-imagine-provider
│   ├── pimple
│   │   └── pimple
│   ├── psr
│   │   └── log
│   ├── silex
│   │   └── silex
│   ├── swiftmailer
│   │   └── swiftmailer
│   ├── symfony
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── debug
│   │   ├── event-dispatcher
│   │   ├── filesystem
│   │   ├── form
│   │   ├── http-foundation
│   │   ├── http-kernel
│   │   ├── icu
│   │   ├── intl
│   │   ├── locale
│   │   ├── options-resolver
│   │   ├── property-access
│   │   ├── routing
│   │   ├── security-core
│   │   ├── security-csrf
│   │   ├── translation
│   │   ├── twig-bridge
│   │   └── validator
│   └── twig
│       └── twig
└── web
    ├── css
    ├── font
    ├── images
    └── js
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "Wanako/Wakano.net",
"require": {
            "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
            "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
            "doctrine/dbal": "2.*",
            "knplabs/repository-service-provider": "dev-master",
            "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.1",
            "symfony/form": "~2.1",
            "symfony/validator": "~2.1",
            "symfony/config": "~2.1",
            "symfony/translation": "~2.1",
            "symfony/locale": "~2.1",
            "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0",
            "igorw/config-service-provider": "~1.1",
            "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.1.2,<4.2-dev",
            "ircmaxell/password-compat": "dev-master",
            "neutron/silex-imagine-provider": "~0.1"
},
"autoload": {
            "psr-0": {
                    "WanaKo": "./src/"
            }
    }
}
```

At line 37 of **app/app.php** I've got:

```
$app->mount('/', new WanaKo\Provider\Controller\HomeController());
```

**homecontroller.php** (in the folder src/wanako/provider/controller/)

```
<?php

namespace WanaKo\Provider\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\ControllerCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class HomeController implements ControllerProviderInterface {
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
    // Bind sub-routes
    $controllers->get('/', array($this, 'home'))->method('GET')->bind('home.news');
    return $controllers;
}

public function home(Application $app) {
    // STUFF
}
```

I've got no clue on this one. Is there something I did wrong? Wrong folder structure? Something I forgot? If anyone needs more info, just ask. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to name your folder structure and files in the correct case for psr0 to work correctly, like this:

```
    src/WanaKo/Provider/Controller/HomeController.php
```

Comment: My HomeController-class is placed in homecontroller.php, which is placed in the folder 'src/wanako/provider/controller/'. Isn't that correct since I've got the namespace WanaKo\Provider\Controller? How should I rearange the folder structure?

Comment: src/WanaKo/Provider/Controller/HomeController.php

Comment: Thanks! Forgot that Linux is case-sensitive.